# ubuntu budgie disk partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ubuntu-budgie

I tried partitioning my 500 GB dard drive on Ubuntu budgie.
But when I choose the amount of disk space and select 'start partition' it gives an error saying the drive is in use.
Even after closing everythng this error exist.
This 500 GB disk is the one on which I have installed ubuntu budgie.
So, how to make partition without losing my data?

Comment: You may need to partition while unmounted, try a bootable gparted dvd or usb drive then make the changes e.g. resize current partition, then create extended partitions in the new unused space as needed.  I believe gparted will recognize that you have data and only allow a size that is safe so that you won't lose data or your current OS installed.